# LOCAL branch of submodule?

Tags: git

I've begun with something like this...

```
%> cd $HOME/project; export PROJECT="${PWD}"; export TOPREPO="${PROJECT}/subs/toprepo
%> git submodule add https://public.com/TopRepo/toprepo.git ${TOPREPO}
%> git submodule update --init --recursive ${TOPREPO}
%> git submodule status --recursive | awk '{print $2}'
subs/toprepo
subs/toprepo/sub1
subs/toprepo/sub1/subsub1
subs/toprepo/sub2
...
```

Now if I modify a file below *our* code (not in submodule), I will see something ordinary like this:

```
%> echo "HACK_1" >> ${PROJECT}/src/foo/foo.cc
%> git status --branch --short -- .
## main...origin/main
 M src/foo/foo.cc
```

However, if I modify a file below the *submodule* OF the *submodule*, I will see something like this:

```
%> echo "HACK_2" >> ${TOPREPO}/sub1/subsub1/src/bar.cc
%> git status --branch --short -- .
## main...origin/main
 M src/foo/foo.cc
 M subs/toprepo            <-- It knows something below here has been modified, but no details
%> git status --branch --short -- ./subs/toprepo
## main...origin/main      <-- This doesn't work. We're in the wrong place.
%> cd ${TOPREPO}/sub1; git status --branch --short -- .
HEAD (no branch)
 m subsub1                 <-- Again, it knows the child has been modified, but no details
%> cd ${TOPREPO}/sub1/subsub1; git status --branch --short -- .
HEAD (no branch)
 m src/bar.cc              <-- Here's HACK_2
```

Today we routinely manage changes that my colleagues and I make within our own code using branches and whatnot.

**I am trying to create that same ability on all the submodules.**

- I cannot *push* any changes (such as my "hack" above) onto `TopRepo` or its submodule repos.
- When changes are made to the `TopRepo` or its submodule repos, I want to be able to pull/merge those changes without losing my "hacks".

It feels like the solution is to make a BRANCH for each of the submodules that I need to "hack".  However, those branches have to be LOCAL!  I cannot push my branch back to the public repo of the submodules.  I *want* those branches/hacks to be stored as part of our "main" repo, but I'm not sure how that could happen...

Let's try:

```
%> cd ${TOPREPO}/sub1/subsub1
%> git checkout -b hack2
M    src/bar.cc
Switched to a new branch 'hack2'
%> git commit -m "HACK2" ./src/bar.cc
[hack2 49b9c3a] HACK2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
%> git status --branch --short -- .
## hack2
%> #    NO PUSH!  NOWHERE TO PUSH!

%> cd ${TOPREPO}/sub1
%> git status --branch --short -- .
## HEAD (no branch)
  M subsub1                 <-- Capital 'M' now...  Hmmm...
%> #    NO NEW BRANCH HERE
```

I don't want to create another branch in repo `sub1`, since the hack/change is below submodule `subsub1`.  The whole point to submodules is to not do that!

However, how do I propagate the change/branch in `subsub` through `sub1` through `toprepo` to `project` where I can store them into our repo?

The end goal is that when I do that initial `git submodule update --init --recursive` on OUR repo, that it somehow applies my hacks applied in all the submodules.

What I *could* do is to simply script it.  Pull down all the code as above, then run a script full of sed/awk/python commands in OUR repo that will apply the hacks we want TODAY.  The problem with that is that when public changes are made to `subsub1` (and all other submodules), I'll have to audit/maintain the scripts.  If I'm able to do this right, `git pull`/`git merge` will do that maintenance work for me.

Comment: I must say I am a bit lost in your question. For starters, you say : "I cannot *push* any changes onto `TopRepo`", do you mean : 1. that you, as a rule, want to avoid doing it ? or 2. "I think I have no way to push to `TopRepo`", but would like to do it ?

Comment: I would say, however, that if you and your colleague own all code, you would probably be better off merging all of the code in one mono repo.

Comment: @LeGEC  We own our code.  The other code we are leveraging (for some testing) is in a public repo.  I cannot (and don't want to) push our changes up there.  No one, except us, want these changes.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should fork the public repos, so now you have your own copy that you can add your hacks (in a way that can be shared with the team) and also easily pull in changes from the upstream when that gets updated.

If you still want to use submodules to pull that all into your project, then you can submodule to the forked repo.

Comment: I think this is probably the best option.  Fork the public repos, apply our changes.  As the public repo progresses, downmerge those changes into our fork, just so we don't get left behind...

I just have to change the submodule that we modify to point to our fork instead of the main.